# Contact Field doesn't work

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I suddenly discovered that my contact field doesn't work. Meaning I most likely have lost alot of emails in the last year... Wops.

Could you please help me to see what's wrong?

I am 100% it worked when I tested it one year ago, but perhaps something in the code or browser settings has been changed.

I have checked my junk in my email, nothing there.

It's in Wordpress and I made a plugin for this.

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name:Haugsdalen_kontakt
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="left" class="eleven columns" >
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <?PHP haugsdalen_kontaktplugin(); ?>    

        </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>   
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Sorry if it's hard to understand the language, but I guess you only will be looking in the code anyways.

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Haugsdalen Skisenter Kontaktskjema
 * Description: Kontaktskjema for Haugsdalen Skisenter
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Ole Andreas Vekve
 * License: GPL2

    Copyright 2013  KANDIDATNUMMER 902

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as 
    published by the Free Software Foundation.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

function test_input_kontakt($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}

function haugsdalen_kontaktplugin () {
    function haugsdalen_kontakt_header () {
    echo ('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'haugsdalen-kontakt.css">');   
    }

    $from = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $to = 'ole.andreas.vekve@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Ny melding fra Haugsdalen Skisenter';

    $body = "Ny melding fra Haugsdalen Skisenter:\n Fra: $name\n E-post: $email\n Melding:\n $message";

    echo ('<div id="kontakthead">');            
    if ($_POST['submit']) {              
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Din melding har blitt sendt!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Noe gikk galt. Vennligst prøv igjen.</p>'; 
    } 
    } 
    echo ('<form method="post" action="http://haugsdalen.com/kontakt/">
    <h2>Kontakt</h2>   
    <label>Navn</label>
    <input name="from" placeholder="Ditt navn">

    <label>E-post</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Din e-post">

    <label>Melding</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Din melding..."></textarea>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send inn"></form><br/>
    <h3><strong>Kontaktinformasjon:</strong></h3>
    Tlf: 73 85 46 05<br/>
    E-post: ole.andreas.vekve@gmail.com<br/>
    </div>');
}
?>
```

Comment: Does it give an error message or anything? It's a little hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the question. No, I only get the message "Din melding har blitt sendt!", (see code) meaning it should be sent.

Comment: @Olen: whatever this language is (I assume one of the Scandinavian ones) – most of us have a hard time understanding it and it makes the code more easy to understand if you used English. Side note: you might want to do internationalization, anyway.

Comment: @Olen: And you definetly want to have some automated tests run once in a while. Have a deep look into Selenium.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, I know, I have translated alot of my posts earlier when they was on Norwegian. But in this case I thought you only would be looking into the code. But I will keep that in mind to the next time, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$from` variable in `if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from))` is the header part where mail is using it as a default `From:`, which in turn is taken from `$from = $_POST['name'];` being a "name". Mail is reading the "From:" as a name. It needs to be an Email address.

Because of this, many Email clients will interpret this as Spam, or discarded altogether.

Mail is reading/interpreting it as `John@inexistant_user_on_yourserver.xxx` therefore  falling back to `xxx@your_hosting_provider_mail.xxx` as being the "From:" instead of `john@his_email_service.xxx`

You need to change that variable to `$email` so that your code now reads as

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $email))
```

For more information on this, read the manual:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php**

Consequently, you could add:

```
$header = "From: ". $from . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";
```

Then change it to:

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $header))
```

which will show mail coming in from a name, while still being a valid/properly formatted Email address.

- **http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mail.php**

---

*Slight edit:*

You also have an undefined variable `$name` in the `$body` which should be `$from` since that is the name part, as per `$from = $_POST['name'];`, however after looking at your form's element `<input name="from" placeholder="Ditt navn">` which looks to mean "name" in your language.

That would need to be changed to `$from = $_POST['from'];`

or change `<input name="from" placeholder="Ditt navn">`

to `<input name="name" placeholder="Ditt navn">`

Comment: Thanks alot. I guess you got the answer. I changed what you suggested and it looks like sometimes the emails get sent to junk, and sometimes not. But it works, thank you very much! My best guess of why this worked a year ago must be that the Email client has changed their 'settings' for spam and so forth. Thank you again.

Comment: @Olen You're quite welcome Olen. Mail nowadays is getting more and more problematic. Most days, mail comes through no problem, while some others are sent to Spam. I also made a few edits along the way in my answer, in case you may not have seen them. Please reload my answer to see the additionals.